# Custom Push and pop Animation iOS 7 and 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7

I am using this code for custom model transition -

> For Push
>
> ```
> CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
> transition.type          = kCATransitionPush;
> transition.duration      = 0.3;
> transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
> transition.subtype       = kCATransitionFromTop;
>
> [view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
> ```
>
> For Pop
>
> ```
> CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
> transition.type          = kCATransitionPush;
> transition.duration      = 0.3;
> transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
> transition.subtype       = kCATransitionFromBottom;
>
> [view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
> ```
>
> view is self.navigationController.view

how can i change this to make - Zoom in and Zoom out animation. any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

Zoom In Animation:

```
self.yourComponent.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"zoomIn" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; // Time in seconds
self.yourComponent.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2); // 20% bigger
```

Zoom Out Animation:

```
self.yourComponent.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"zoomOut" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; // Time in seconds
self.yourComponent.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
```

`self.yourComponent` can be a `UIView`, `UIImageView`, `UIButton` or any other component.